How to add a dynamic route guard in angular from a JSON value?
I am trying to add the route guard in my angular app.
I am building the routes dynamically from a JSON which has the following structure
 {
      "path": "software-upgrade",
      "title": "Software Upgrade",
      "canActivate": "AuthGuard",  // This is the route guard name
      "isMFE": true,
      "loadRemoteModule": {
        "type": "manifest",
        "remoteName": "software-upgrade",
        "exposedModule": "./Module"
      },
      "moduleName": "SoftwareUpgradeModule"
    },

I am using the value of canActivate while building the route like this
routeArr.push({
          path: route.path,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],   // this works
          // canActivate: [route.canActivate], // this does not work even though it is fetching the same value from JSON
        });

I get the following error in console if i use the value from the JSON but the same thing works if I directly specify the value of the guard.

Is there any way of handling this?

Does this answer your question? Dynamically loading a typescript class (reflection for typescript)

where is  route.canActivate ? Is it in a file which is already loaded or you want to dynamically load the file and the function?

i fetch that file via REST API and it is available at the time of building the route

@YongShun no it does not answer my question

sorry , i didn't get fetch file vis REST API ? do you mean to write the file is already in code base & packed and you dynamically load it ? by fetch file it mean to me that you are downloading a file from server

I meant i have the file in assets and i fetch it via angular http call.
Anyways got the solution below

You need to create an object map, where the key will be the authGuard and the value will be AuthGuard (the actual import)
import { AuthGuard } from 'some path';

export const DYNAMIC_ROUTING_MAP = {
    'authGuard': AuthGuard,
    ...
}

Then on the dynamic routing, we can simply get the reference and set it!
routeArr.push({
   path: route.path,
   canActivate: [DYNAMIC_ROUTING_MAP[route.canActivate]], // <- changed here!
});

